# s3 endpoint timeout error

Tags: amazon-s3, endpoint, aws-security-group

Can you pls help to troubleshooot timeout error for S3 endpoint. It looks like a timeout on firewall.

I have followed the instructions here - https://aws.amazon.com/premiumsupport/knowledge-center/connect-s3-vpc-endpoint/ but i just can't see the error.

This is test VPC:
[MyVPC](https://i.stack.imgur.com/cU5lE.png)

THis is private subnet with its route table (this is active):
[private subnet](https://i.stack.imgur.com/8dGCb.png)

This is NACL - everything is open:
[NACL](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YoqfN.png)

And this is security group for instance with no ip in the private subnet:
[security group](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mAw8n.png)

What else should i check?

I can't execute a command like "aws s3 ls". It looks like timeout - no error message
If i'm using IGW all is working fine.

Any ideas?

Comment: Is the bucket in the same region as the instance?  S3 endpoints don't provide cross-region access.

Comment: Sorry, forget to write about it. Yes, it's the same region. Frankfurt.